# Fixed Position in responsive design

Tags: css, scroll, responsive-design, css-position

I am using responsive framework 1140px. In the mobile version I have to fix the position of a logo but not have it overlap the content on scroll. Basically fix the position but don't fix the image on scroll, can this be achieved?

Comment: By your definition you don't want fixed, you want absolute.

Comment: The only way that would be possible is to have your wrapper `overlflow-y:scroll;` and body `overflow: hidden`;  this is the same effect you see on websites like themeforest, when you view a page and it says hide frame. Am i right?

Comment: oh, and the height of your logo as the `margin-top` of your wrapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you want is `position: absolute`, the difference being that absolute images do not move while scrolling.
http://www.impressivewebs.com/absolute-position-css/

It's worth taking a look at this link in order to see the differences between relative, absolute, and fixed positioning:
http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 7):

You want to use `position:absolute`

- `position:fixed` fixes the element to the screen, so it will not move when you scroll (it's fixed to the window).
- `position:absolute` fixes the element based on the closest `ancestor` that is not `position:static`, so it will move when you scroll the page (it's fixed to the page).