# Keep header position fixed while scrolling on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

So I have a `position: fixed;` header and works fine on desktop.

However, when I'm scrolling on Mobile, it takes awhile for it to figure out where I'm scrolling to. So the header isn't fixed until I've stopped scrolling on mobile then the header jumps to the position it should be.

Any workaround or fix for this?

```
   <div class="mobile-header">
      <a href="#" class="mobile-header-button">Open/close</a>
      <a href="/" class="mobile-header-home">Home</a>
      <ul class="mobile-header-searchbutton">
        <li class="search-button"><a href="/search">Search</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

The above is the HTML, and below is my css.

```
.mobile-header {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  height: 62px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: left .2s;
  -o-transition: left .2s;
  transition: left .2s;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

So this is my position fixed header. When I scroll on desktop it's fixed, but when I scroll on mobile, it lags behind my scrolling.

Comment: Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: read this plz.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650056/fixed-position-in-responsive-design

Comment: Sorry @SuperBiasedMan only reason I didn't was literally because, it's just a position fixed header. Nothing really that code would explain any further

Comment: @GoodOldSnoopy Even minimal code that looks fine can give people a starting point for how to tackle the problem, and since it's short it's not going to unduly take up space.

Comment: Thanks @AlexKante but `position: absolute;` isn't what i'm looking for. I want the header to be fixed to the top of the viewport (screen) at all times even when scrolling.

Currently, when I scroll on mobile. It disappears then jumps back down to me when I stop scrolling. Setting it as `position: absolute;` wouldn't fix this.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan My bad, i've just updated my answer with some code. It's quite basic, i'm not sure if it's something i've done or just an issue with mobile that I haven't addressed

Answer (score 0):

I've found `position: fixed;` to be quite problematic on some mobiles. I think it's the touch-drag interface that seems to break the functionality. It seems that some fixed layouts are just a little too complex for some (usually older) mobiles to comprehend.

What you can do, is try to limit the amount of elements that are being fixed, and if possible only apply that style to a top-level element, rather than a nested one. The 'real' behaviour of `fixed` means it shouldn't matter if it's embedded inside other `position`ed elements, but from past experience I've had issues when nesting a fixed element inside an absolute one.

I would test a layout in it's most simple form to see if you can make a single element fixed and behave as expected first. If that works, then try to simplify your header code as much as possible.